# Bootstrap 4 dropdown in react - toggle and close on click outside component

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I do want to use Bootstrap 4 in react natively (without 3rd party libs). The dropdown toggle (especially closing the dropdown-menu) must be controlled by a dedicated function. The reason is that the dropdown-menu must be able to receive multiple click events. The normal behavior by BS is that it's closing after the first click.

[Bootstrap Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/dropdowns/#usage) suggests to use `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()` when using JavaScript but I'd prefer not to use jQuery and refs in react.

The following code is working but I doubt it is good practice. What's the best practice solution here?

```
toggleDropdown = () => {
    document.getElementById("dropdownMenu").style.display = document.getElementById("dropdownMenu").style.display === "" ? "block" : "";
};

render() {
    <div className="dropdown">
        <button
            onClick={this.toggleDropdown}
            className="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
            type="button"
            id="dropdownMenuButton">
            Dropdown button
        </button>
        <div id="dropdownMenu" className="dropdown-menu p-4 text-muted" style={{maxWidth: "200px"}}>
            <p>Some example text that's free-flowing within the dropdown menu.</p>
        </div>
     </div>
}
```

Comment: May I ask why this question is receiving -1?

Comment: @admins: Please consider to revise the -1. The answer to the question is not as obvious as it looks in the first round. Its not just a `state` controlled toogle-pattern. The answer must take the BS Documentation into consideration.

Comment: This question belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

First thought: ToggleDropdown can be written like this(more dynamic).

```
toggleDropdown = (e) => {
  var elem = e.target.nextElementSibling.classList;
  elem.contains('show') ? elem.remove('show') : elem.add('show');
};
```

Comment: Note: your second line can be simplified to `elem.toggle('show');`

Answer (score -1):

This involves the basic usage of state in React.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    show: false,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="dropdown">
        <button
          onClick={() => this.setState((prevState) => ({ show: !prevState.show }))}
          className="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
          type="button"
          id="dropdownMenuButton"
        >
          Dropdown button
        </button>
        {this.state.show && (
          <div
            id="dropdownMenu"
            className="dropdown-menu p-4 text-muted"
            style={{ maxWidth: '200px' }}
          >
            <p>Some example text that's free-flowing within the dropdown menu.</p>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't change the initial state of the `dropdown-menu` class by BS where `display` is set to `""`

Comment: Are you trying to hide the `dropdownMenu` component?

Comment: well I'm trying to toggle it cotrolled by a function without the use of BS `data-toggle`-attribute

Comment: So does my code above achieve it? Remove the `display` property completely from ur css, this solution does not need to rely on css.

Comment: No. Not with BS standard classes. My question was unprecise. I'm looking for an alternative to what [BS Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/dropdowns/#usage) suggests. Without use of jQuery & react-refs, without changing BS classes, without adding any further css

Comment: Oh i see...you can try https://react-bootstrap.github.io/ which abstracts away the DOM manipulation so you can rely purely on states/props.

Comment: Thanks but that is exactly what I don't want and furthermore: "React-Bootstrap currently targets Bootstrap v3."

Comment: this hides the dropdown and I have to click on the button again to show the new list